# Sort NSMutableDictionary by key name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, sorting, ios7

Hi i am working on sorting feature in my application. in which i am facing strange issue to i am hoping for get help.

Please check the example data as follows: (NSMutableDictionary)

```
{
NameArray =     (
        kniteman,
        Acrix,
        Bahel,
        Mayur,
        vasel,
        Mayur
    );
    NoArray =     (
        3261,
        1800,
        3366,
        4000,
        1099,
        1999
    );
```

Now above is the Dictionary data i have shown NSLog results.

I want to sort this dictionary with NameArray key.

Any hint or guidance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have a dictionary which contains arrays and you want to sort one of the arrays? Because you can't sort a dictionary.

Comment: @Wain i want to sort whole dictionary on basis on NameArray. It means NoArray value will also be sort according to NameArray.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using a dictionary. You should have an array of dictionaries where each dictionary contains your 2 keys with appropriate (linked) values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sort a dictionary as dictionaries, by definition, have no order. You'll want an array of dictionaries instead. This will keep the name and number values together at all times. Assuming you have both `NameArray` and `NoArray` loaded into `NSArrays` and they are in the same order, you can load them into an array of dictionaries like so:

```
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray array];

// check for equal counts to avoid error
if ([NameArray count] == [NoArray count])
{
    NSUInteger count = [NameArray count];

    // loop through and add an NSDictionary for each item
    for (NSUInteger i; i < count; i++)
    {
        [list addObject:@{@"name" : [NameArray objectAtIndex:i],
                        @"number": [NoArray objectAtIndex:i]}];
    }
}
```

The array of dictionaries may now be sorted like so:

```
NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES] autorelease];

NSArray *sortedArray = [list sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[nameDescriptor]];
[list setArray:sortedArray];
```

Comment: Done it by using your solution thanks.